# MongoDB query returns empty result after Openshift migration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, openshift

I have the following problem: my application runs correctly on localhost, but not on my Openshift platform.

I have a MongoDB database, with a NodeJS back-end working with socket.io.

This is the URL to connect to my database:

```
var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/db';

if (process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD) {
   connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
   process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
   process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
   process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
   process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}
```

This is how I connect to the database:
`mongodb.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + connection_string, function(err, db) {`

This is how my socket is connected (Openshift case):
`var socket = io.connect("http://nodejs-myapp.rhcloud.com:8000"); //io(); for localhost case`

This is the query I'm doing:

```
db.collection('tobaccoStores').ensureIndex({Coordinates:"2dsphere"}).then(function(result) {
    db.collection('tobaccoStores').find({
                "Coordinates": {$near:
                                {$geometry:
                                    {type:"Point", coordinates:[coords.coords.lng, coords.coords.lat]},
                                  $maxDistance: coords.maxdistance
                                }
                }
            })
```

And so, when running on localhost my queries return the right results, but not on my Openshift application. Moreover, when I run the query in the mongo shell on my Openshift application, the right results are also returned...

Comment: Are you using the same versions of MongoDB on both dev and Openshift systems?  I think Openshift I'd running 2.6.

Comment: Indeed, the MongoDB version on my local computer is 3.0.6, and 2.4 on my Openshift application. But what would it change ? Queries seem to be the same...

Comment: @blondie I recommend trying to downgrade your local mongodb version and test it

Comment: @blondie, the are definitely not the same.  I ran into to other issues and had to downgrade.

Comment: On the documentation of MongoDB, it says : "Once upgraded to MongoDB 3.0, you cannot downgrade to a version lower than 2.6.5". Any idea how should I proceed ? I have dowloaded the exact version of the MongoDB on Openshift, and when trying to run it, it says there is a problem with my database version, which seems logic...

Comment: I have restored my 3.0 database into the 2.4.9 database. Now my localhost application is not working when connected to the 2.4.9 database. But query in the mongo still works (as it worked on Openshift mongo shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: from my nodejs application I was connecting to a database which is not the same to which you are connected by default when you run `mongo` on your Openshift server. My data was not in the right database... did not pay attention to this details.